# How to configure relationship using Entity framework fluent api for below use case

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with Code First approach and i have designed below classes.

```
public interface IItem
 {
        public Guid ItemId { get; set; }

        DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

        DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }

        User CreatedBy { get; set; }

        User ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    }

    public class User : IItem
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Guid ItemId { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }

        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entity1 : IItem
    {
        public string Entity1Prop1 { get; set; }

        public Guid ItemId { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }

        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

Now i need to define relation between the entities using fluent API.
I have below requirement
1. User table has primary key ItemId
2. User table colulmns CreatedBy and ModifiedBy reference to same user table ItemId column  as ForeignKey
3. Entity1 table has primary key ItemId
4. Entity table columns CreatedBy and ModifiedBy references to user table itemId   as foreign key

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Need to configure relationship between the tables with below mentioned requirement 1. User table has primary key ItemId 2. User table colulmns CreatedBy and ModifiedBy reference to same user table ItemId column as ForeignKey 3. Entity1 table has primary key ItemId 4. Entity table columns CreatedBy and ModifiedBy references to user table itemId as foreign key

Comment: Here is a good place to start : http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx